# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 installation failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I have a problem with installation Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3. I don't know what cause the problem, but setup is failed every time in each setup configuration. Setup manager shows me following error and warning:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Services Hub
>
> The system cannot open the device or file specified

[image: Screenshot]

I really don't know how to solve this problem. Does anyone know what is wrong and how can I install this program?

Greetings

Comment: Examine the log file, as the dialog suggests. Clicking the link will open the log file in Notepad. Look for any lines with `ERROR` in them.

Comment: There is too much errors to paste them directly here due to the limit of the number of characters. Here I send you a link where you can see all errors from log file - http://ctrlv.it/id/8355/2538767987

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

I know what was the problem! I didn't check thoroughly the **default location** where Visual Studio wants to install. On my PC I have installed a 64-bit Windows 7. After many tries of installation I saw that installator chose wrong *Program Files* folder. It tries to install Visual Studio in **Program Files (x86)** (dedicated for 32-bit programs). I really don't know why VS installator chose a default folder for a 32-bit programs while my VS is a 64-bit version and also Windows is a 64-bit version.

I hope that this **solution** will help someone who has the same problem.

Comment: you should mark your solution as answer and it will help other community members who have the same or similar issue to easier find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is because of Windows Installer cannot access the `%TEMP%` folder (I had similar error once, but with MSSQL setup). So:

- First of all check if you `%TEMP%` environment variable points to the
  right location
- Then check if the account which is running VS setup has privileges to
  access `TEMP` folder. Better yet, make sure you run setup as
  administrator
- Finally make sure you have disabled all disk or folder encryption
  features
- Also just to be sure disable any antivirus software you have running

Comment: Suggestion #3 is very, very bad. There's nothing wrong with encryption. Disabling it though will *decrypt* everything. Suggestion #4 isnt' that bad, just not needed. Suggestions #1, #2 mean that the *user* changed the values to point to another disk or folder. By default %TEMP% points to a folder in the user's profile.

Comment: Arbitrary system changes won't help if one doesn't know what's actually wrong. They can cause a lot of damage though

Answer (score 0):

The error message “The system cannot open the device or file specified” often related to the specific folder is encrypted, you can have a look at this article and try the following methods:

1. Save the VS installer file to a folder that is not encrypted
2. Install the VS to a folder that is not encrypted
3. Turn off encryption on the %temp% folder

To check the encryption of the specific folder, you can right click the folder and select ‘Properties’— ‘General’ tab, click ‘Advanced’ button and confirm the checkbox of ‘Encrypt contents to secure data’ is checked or not.

You can click the ‘log file’ in the VS installer screen that you shared, and find the specific folders that these 2 components ‘Microsoft Visual Studio Services Hub’ and ‘Visual C++ IDE Common Package’ stores and check if those folders are encrypted or not.